# null pointer check didn't prevent memcpy crash

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, memcpy

I have some c++ function which runs on ARM platform and works well for months, but recently it ran into memcpy() SIGSEGV issue, I just have no clue why this happened, any help is appreciated.

The code snip looks like below, gdb shows 'buffer' is null pointer, but this has been checked at line 651:

```
649         uint8_t* buffer = new uint8_t [frameInfo->size];
650         assert(buffer != nullptr);
651         if (buffer == nullptr) 
652         {
653             LOG_ERROR() << "Failed to created video frame";
654             return nullptr;
655         }
656         std::memcpy(buffer, frameInfo->omxBuf->pBuffer, frameInfo->size);
```

Coredump backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000007fb8741cc0 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000005587dc4bc8 in memcpy (__len=<optimized out>, __src=<optimized out>, __dest=0x0) at /opt/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include/bits/string_fortified.h:34
#2  stream::OmxVideoDecoderImpl::get_video_frame (this=0x7f8c001e60, frameInfo=0x7f8c001fb0)
    at /home/li/vs/test_monkey/src/decoder/omxdecoder/omx_video_decoder.cpp:656
Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fa5ff85c8
(gdb) f 2
#2  stream::OmxVideoDecoderImpl::get_video_frame (this=0x7f8c001e60, frameInfo=0x7f8c001fb0)
    at /home/li/vs/test_monkey/src/decoder/omxdecoder/omx_video_decoder.cpp:656
656            std::memcpy(buffer, frameInfo->omxBuf->pBuffer, frameInfo->size);
(gdb) p buffer
$7 = (uint8_t *) 0x0
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function stream::OmxVideoDecoderImpl::get_video_frame(stream::OmxDecodedFrameInfo*):
   0x0000005587dc4b70 <+0>: sub sp, sp, #0x260
   0x0000005587dc4b74 <+4>: stp x29, x30, [sp, #32]
   0x0000005587dc4b78 <+8>: add x29, sp, #0x20
   0x0000005587dc4b7c <+12>:    stp x19, x20, [sp, #48]
   0x0000005587dc4b80 <+16>:    stp x21, x22, [sp, #64]
   0x0000005587dc4b84 <+20>:    mov x21, x8
   0x0000005587dc4b88 <+24>:    mov x20, x0
   0x0000005587dc4b8c <+28>:    mov x19, x1
   0x0000005587dc4b90 <+32>:    adrp    x0, 0x558897d000
   0x0000005587dc4b94 <+36>:    ldr x0, [x0, #1272]
   0x0000005587dc4b98 <+40>:    ldr x1, [x0]
   0x0000005587dc4b9c <+44>:    str x1, [sp, #600]
   0x0000005587dc4ba0 <+48>:    mov x1, #0x0                    // #0
   0x0000005587dc4ba4 <+52>:    cbz x19, 0x5587dc4c04 <stream::OmxVideoDecoderImpl::get_video_frame(stream::OmxDecodedFrameInfo*)+148>
   0x0000005587dc4ba8 <+56>:    stp x23, x24, [sp, #80]
   0x0000005587dc4bac <+60>:    ldr x0, [x19]
   0x0000005587dc4bb0 <+64>:    bl  0x5587c22180 <operator new[](unsigned long)>
   0x0000005587dc4bb4 <+68>:    mov x23, x0
   0x0000005587dc4bb8 <+72>:    ldr x1, [x19, #96]
   0x0000005587dc4bbc <+76>:    ldr x2, [x19]
   0x0000005587dc4bc0 <+80>:    ldr x1, [x1, #8]
   0x0000005587dc4bc4 <+84>:    bl  0x5587bd6a80 <memcpy@plt>
=> 0x0000005587dc4bc8 <+88>:    add x22, sp, #0x88
   0x0000005587dc4bcc <+92>:    add x0, x22, #0x10
   0x0000005587dc4bd0 <+96>:    str x0, [sp, #136]
   0x0000005587dc4bd4 <+100>:   mov w3, #0x0                    // #0
```

After removing assert of line 650, it seems the assembly code has no change:

```
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function stream::OmxVideoDecoderImpl::get_video_frame(stream::OmxDecodedFrameInfo*):
   0x00000055925dde08 <+0>: sub sp, sp, #0x260
   0x00000055925dde0c <+4>: stp x29, x30, [sp, #32]
   0x00000055925dde10 <+8>: add x29, sp, #0x20
   0x00000055925dde14 <+12>:    stp x19, x20, [sp, #48]
   0x00000055925dde18 <+16>:    stp x21, x22, [sp, #64]
   0x00000055925dde1c <+20>:    mov x21, x8
   0x00000055925dde20 <+24>:    mov x20, x0
   0x00000055925dde24 <+28>:    mov x19, x1
   0x00000055925dde28 <+32>:    adrp    x0, 0x559318c000
   0x00000055925dde2c <+36>:    ldr x0, [x0, #1272]
   0x00000055925dde30 <+40>:    ldr x1, [x0]
   0x00000055925dde34 <+44>:    str x1, [sp, #600]
   0x00000055925dde38 <+48>:    mov x1, #0x0                    // #0
   0x00000055925dde3c <+52>:    cbz x19, 0x55925dde9c <stream::OmxVideoDecoderImpl::get_video_frame(stream::OmxDecodedFrameInfo*)+148>
   0x00000055925dde40 <+56>:    stp x23, x24, [sp, #80]
   0x00000055925dde44 <+60>:    ldr x0, [x19]
   0x00000055925dde48 <+64>:    bl  0x559243b200 <operator new[](unsigned long)>
   0x00000055925dde4c <+68>:    mov x23, x0
   0x00000055925dde50 <+72>:    ldr x1, [x19, #96]
   0x00000055925dde54 <+76>:    ldr x2, [x19]
   0x00000055925dde58 <+80>:    ldr x1, [x1, #8]
   0x00000055925dde5c <+84>:    bl  0x55923efad0 <memcpy@plt>
   0x00000055925dde60 <+88>:    add x22, sp, #0x88
   0x00000055925dde64 <+92>:    add x0, x22, #0x10
   0x00000055925dde68 <+96>:    str x0, [sp, #136]
   0x00000055925dde6c <+100>:   mov w3, #0x0                    // #0
```

Comment: Is that assert part of your code? It’s possible the compiler is seeing the assert and logically deducing that the pointer can’t be null so removes your if check?

Comment: I can remove the assert, but if it's the case, why assert is not triggered? May compiler also optimize out the assert?

Comment: Depending on how the build process is defined, asserts won't make it to production code.

Comment: After removing assert, the assembly code seems no change, I updated the question

Comment: The compiler knows that the result of a non-overridden `new` can never be a null pointer.

Comment: Unfortunately my project overrides new() for accounting memory usage, then how to enforce compiler not to remove null pointer check?

Comment: There is a compiler flag you can try. `no-delete-null-pointer-checks` Might work, might not.

Comment: The title to this question is unreadable and without context meaningless.

Comment: Unadorned `new` does not return `nullptr` on failure, so the assert and the check serve no purpose.  You should either catch the exception or include `<new>` and use `uint8_t* buffer = new(std::nothrow) uint8_t[frameInfo->size];`.

Comment: `assert` is a no-op if `NDEBUG` is defined, which will be the case if you have not built the code with debug info.  The lack of change is unsurprising.

Comment: "_my project overrides new() for accounting memory usage_" that information, and the override should be in the question; it is likely that that is where the error is.  Either way, you have not implemented it with the expected semantics that the optimiser assumes, so that it removes the "redundant" checks.  I'd post that as an answer if the necessary information were in the question - can't answer a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Taekahn and @j6t , either replace new() with malloc() or add compile option -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks can force compiler not remove null pointer check and avoid segment fault.

Comment: That is not really a solution however.  Your `new` override is incorrect if it returns `nullptr` rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: Thanks Clifford, you're right: the overridden new can return nullptr. But I won't touch it since it's been there for years and the product have been released with it.

Comment: @wenshi : That is probably wise, but if you were to add an override for `new(std::nothrow)` perhaps and map it to your non-throwing `new` replacement, then you can write robust and portable code without having to worry about what the optimiser might do on any particular compiler version/platform.